# Can you recommend a good modern GUI download manager (wget wrapper?)

Tags: downloads, software-recommendation

"Downloader for X" looks, heh, not fitting well into Ubuntu theme and not very natural/convenient. At the same time I don't know of any good alternative. Maybe you know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Gwget](http://projects.gnome.org/gwget/) [image: Install gwget]

> Gwget is a free graphical frontend for of Wget. GWget supports all of the main features that Wget does, as well as parallel downloads. Its name is derived from GUI - Graphical user interface, and Wget.

You can also install it by

```
sudo apt-get install gwget
```

## [Multiget](http://multiget.sourceforge.net/) [image: Install multiget]

> MultiGet is an easy-to-use GUI file
>   downloader.  It's programmed in C++
>   and has a GUI based on wxWidgets. It
>   supports HTTP/FTP protocols which
>   covers the requirements of most users.
>   It supports multi-task with
>   multi-thread on multi-server. It
>   supports resuming downloads if the Web
>   server supports it, and if you like,
>   you can reconfig the thread number
>   without stopping the current task.
>   It's also support SOCKS 4,4a,5 proxy,
>   ftp proxy, http proxy.
>   In v0.8.0, a new feature was introduced, that is so called P2SP, or in other words,  get file from multiple servers, and combine the data from different site into one file. This makes downloads complete much faster.

You can also install it by

```
sudo apt-get install multiget
```

## [Fatrat](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/) [image: Install fatrat]

> Fatrat is an open source download manager for Linux written in C++ and built on top of the Trolltech Qt 4 library. It is rich in features and is continuously extended.

You can also install it by

```
sudo apt-get install fatrat
```

## [Uget](http://urlget.sourceforge.net/) [image: Install uget]

> Uget (formerly urlgfe) is a Free and Open Source download manager written in GTK+ , it has many of features like easy-to-use , cross-platform (Windows & GNU/Linux) , support pause and resume , classify download , every category has an independent configuration , and more ...

You can also install it by

```
sudo apt-get install uget
```

Comment: multiget cannot resume downloads properly from crashes. my vote goes to fatrat

Answer (score 5):

[Steadyflow](https://launchpad.net/steadyflow):

[image]

To install, run this from a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sikon/steadyflow

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install steadyflow
```

Comment: Looks pretty, but misses a lot of handy features (like storing history of previously used save file names and locations, limiting quantity of simultaneously downloaded files, multipart downloading, reserving disk space at download start, etc.) and ... despite humble look is extremely CPU-consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you use Firefox, I'd suggest to use [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/). It does not only support multiple downloads and pausing/resuming, but also multiple connections for one download.

Comment: I prefer not using Firefox downlads extensions as this introduces some problems with downloads in some cases I've experienced. DownThemAll still can't manage to download some files of those meant only for browser access, and even having DownThemAll or FlashGot installed introduces some inconveniences in some cases. So I am looking for a browser-independent external download manager, ideally a wget GUI wrapper.

Comment: A browser isnt the best option do download big files

Answer (score 2):

[jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) can be an option? It has been made for other manners, but has the 'link grabber' function that can be usefull: while youre surfing, he grab all the links you select in web pages, and then you can download one by one or all of them.

It has even a captcha OCR, but im not sure if is your case ;)

Comment: Yes it can (I used to use it when I was using Windows, and was pretty satisfied), but a zip package (I prefer to use Java apps in a "portable" manner rather than installing them into system with dpkg) was removed from the server (they use ul.to, so it's not surprising). I've submitted an issue, hope they are going to reupload.

Answer (score 2):

[kget](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/kget/): Downloads from FTP, HTTP(S), torrent sources simultaneously, scriptable, automatic mirror search and more..
[image]

Comment: kget suffers a big problem, if the internet drops for some time then the download will stall and wont resume for a long time even if the internet connection is up again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out flareGet ( a recently released download manager for linux). It is still in the alpha stage but works pretty good. It is multi-threaded and supports upto 16 segments per download for download acceleration. For browser integration you can use flashgot.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/

[image]

Comment: its very buggy at the moment.