# download acceleration with multiple connections

Tags: download-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you recommend a good modern GUI download manager (wget wrapper?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11633/can-you-recommend-a-good-modern-gui-download-manager-wget-wrapper)

I'm trying to find a good download manager that can open concurrent connections for a single download.

I don't mind whether it's an extension (I'm using chrome), or an independent application.

I have downloaded steadyflow, but it doesn't seems to have an concurrent connections option.

Comment: I don't know about concurrent connections and i don't know if this is available for chrome/ium.... Try the Firefox add on download them all... its goooood :)

Comment: Unless you're downloading file fragments from multiple sources, this shouldn't make a noticeable improvement to download speed unless the source imposes per-connection speed caps.

Comment: Ugh -- the possible duplicate is not a good question, though the answers are.  I could see merging/closing if someone made the other more general, but the requirements aren't the same, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Jdownloader](http://jdownloader.org/). It works great for me.Needs a bit of tweaking before you use it
It can open concurrent connections for a single download.
hope it fulfills your need

Comment: If you have any problems regarding this feel free to ask

Answer (score 5):

Add the packages **uget** and **aria2**. Start uGet then go to settings and enable the aria2 plugin, this is needed for multi-threaded downloads. You'll need to manually specify the number of connections when you add new downloads, but other than that little annoyance it's a great app.

I am having problems whitelisting the indicator icon for this app, however, and need to minimize to the dock instead. Unity-2d-panel has more problems with indicator icons than the standard unity-panel so it may not affect you. I'll report back if i find a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out flareGet ( a recently released download manager for linux). It is still in the alpha stage but works pretty good. It is multi-threaded and supports upto 16 segments per download for download acceleration. For browser integration you can use flashgot.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/

[image]

Comment: outdated post. flareget is limiting the number of connections with every new free version.  (the payed version goes up to 32 connections) - more [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/340439/47206)

Comment: do you still have around that alpha version :) ??? that would be useful