# How can I get older version of Flareget?

Tags: download-manager

I had just updated FlareGet download manager and it looks like the new version (1.5.12) allows fewer segments per download than the older one, 1.4.9 (4 instead of 8 - while the pro version offers 16).

[image]

How can I get back the older version?

---

UPDATE: The newer 2.0 version has limited farther the number of segments per download: only 2 for the free version. It looks they are pushing hard their paid version. So, unless buying that, there's no point in upgrading.

v. 2.3-24 allows a max of 16 connection/download but only 2 for a file over 25 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they're restricting connections-per-download to push the paid version.

Given that it's non-free and they control the downloads (and delete their old versions), I don't know what your options are here short of finding somewhere else that has held on to an old copy of one of their debs.

I'd start looking in binary warehouses like Softpedia ([they have it here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/flareGet-1-4-9-Popular-Download-Manager-Improves-Google-Chrome-Support-354726.shtml)) who tend to be pretty slow at deleting old things. Softpedia has already updated in this case, but others may have older binaries. Searching for the filename `flareget_1.4-9_amd64.deb` may work... But I shouldn't have to remind you what horrible security ramifications this has.

I would personally just find something else. Axel, FlashGot, JDownloader2, FATRAT for some examples. There are many out there.

Comment: the Softpedia link re-directs to the latest version

Comment: So it does. I've edited slightly but I don't think I have any good news for you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching to uGet. http://uGetdm.com

uGet is crazy fast, very stable, long track record and completely open source...so no feature restrictions.

More importantly for this case, uGet can make up to 20 connections/segments.

Comment: please post a screenshot of the two on XFCE...I dont have XFCE so I dont have a reference. As far as the youtube filename goes, are you using Firefox and Flashgot? If so then that is the problem, Flashgot doesn't send the filename correctly to uGet so uGet has to compensate. I am in the process of trying to get that fixed though.

Comment: That doesn't look exactly how we wanted it but it is close. We don't like giant buttons that take up that much space. FlashGot has so many users I don't think there is a competitor to it. You can do a temporary fizz yourself though. I will write a tutorial and post it on our site that shows how to do that.

Comment: fix replied to your new topic, http://askubuntu.com/questions/344023/can-uget-downloader-be-used-as-downloader-for-firefox-without-flashgot/344071#344071

Comment: so, uGet is surely multi-thread: can i see the multiple sections? downloading the same video from youtube with uGet and Flareget (1.5 - with 4 fragment sources), uGet gives me the same speed as the default Firefox manager - Flareget much more. are there some settings to make?

Comment: I answered this in the other uGet specific thread.

Comment: uGet supports multiple sections only if aria2 plugin is enabled, but with aria2 enabled stability if uGet is bad. without aria2 plugin, uGet is not faster then any ordinary browser downloader. Its nice and easy downloader to use but needs some more work under the hood, especially with aria2 implementation.

Comment: now curl with multi-connections too. only that the default number is 1. this can be changed in all category -> properties