# Can uGet downloader be used as downloader for Firefox without Flashgot?

Tags: firefox, uget

I use Flashgot and know what it can do, but it seems that at least for the moment there's a problem with the way it works with uGet in recognizing the names of videos (see a comment under [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/340477/47206)).

I would like to know if one can use [this](http://ugetdm.com/) good downloader with Firefox without this addon being involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

There is not a uGet specific addon because of the addons already that make this possible but if you don't want to use FlashGot then you can use [OpenWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/?src=search).

OpenWith is designed to open up links in different browsers but you can add uGet instead.

### Edited on March 7th, 2014:

**The issue that was solved below is no longer an issue with the latest version of FlashGot so if you have an old version just update it and the issue will be fixed.**

However, the problem that you have with FlashGot can be solved by adding a new entry in FlashGot and filling it out like the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: well, after testing uget a bit more and having solved the video name issue i see that the uget speed is the same as that of the firefox default manager, while other multi-thread downloaders provide much superior speeds. i fear there is some setting i might have missed

Comment: uGet uses two download engines as the backend. Default is curl and the other is aria2. Aria2 adds multi-connections to uGet. Settings -> Plugin -> Enable plugin. You will need aria2 installed before enabling the plugin...otherwise you will receive an error.

Comment: Youtube does not allow accelerating or multiconnections...this is a limitation of youtube and is irrelevant what manager you use. uGet is much more than just for downloading from youtube.

Comment: in a now deleted post i had said that a new free version flareget has again many connections per download. that is true, but only for files under 25 MB - which is useless. so much for flareget. so, i will be soon interested in using uGet again. but youtube is not limiting nos of conn./down. I have just used flareget for an under 20 MB file and it used 16 connections - [image here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jMCG7.png)

Comment: you can use multiple connections on the same file with uGet and you will get the exact same result...Youtube only limits after a percentage of the file has been downloaded around 30%-40% of completion. This does not apply to files under 20mb because they are too small to notice...with a decent connection that could take less than a few seconds so Youtube limit wouldn't be noticeable.